# How can I use in Makefile files, that are created in runtime?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am making Static Site Generator using make.

Basically I take .RST files and create .HTML files, which is easy.

```
TARGETS_R = $(shell find . -name '*.rst')
TARGETS_H = $(TARGETS_R:.rst=.html)
regular_files: $(TARGETS_H)
    @echo "Generating HTML files and tag files..."
%.html: %.rst
    @./compile.py $< $@ # create also tags/<tag_name>.tag files as side-effect
```

Problem is, that the source files contains tags, so the tags/*.tag files are known only after all .RST are processed. I would like to make a navigation.nav file like this

```
TARGETS_R = $(shell find . -name '*.rst')
TARGETS_H = $(TARGETS_R:.rst=.html)
regular_files: $(TARGETS_H)
    @echo "Generating HTML files and tag files..."
%.html: %.rst
    @./compile.py $< $@ @# create also tags/<tag_name>.tag files as side-effect
# -----------
TAGS = $(shell find . -name '*.tag')
NAVS = $(TAGS:.tag=.nav)
navigation.nav: $(NAVS)
    echo $^ >$@ # some magic here
%.nav: %.tag
    echo $^ >$@ # some magic here

.PHONY: all regular_files

all: regular_files navigation.nav
```

but it on its first run just make `.html` and `.tag` files and then it need second run, where it makes the `.nav` files from (now existing) `.tag` files

I also would like to use -j24 to use all my cores for work on it.

How could I do that?

Comment: (I also asked chatGPT, but it does not understand the problem at all)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no way that Make can determine beforehand which tag files will exist, then there is no sense in trying to make them prerequisites.

```
navigation.nav: build_navs
    navs=`find . -name '*.nav'`; echo $$navs # some magic here
build_navs:
    tags=`find . -name '*.tag'`; foreach tag ($$tags) echo $$tag # some magic here
```

Comment: Thanks, it could work too, but I would like to use all cores (and there are more things, that would be needed after this pass too - the example was really simplified). 
So I will rather run the command more times, if there would not be better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of automatic makefiles rebuild feature to do that. The idea is to generate a marker file, e.g. `.tagcheck` that will be created every time the `.rst` file is parsed and let `make` include those (empty) marker files. This will cause makefiles re-read and all the rules re-evaluated, which now will also include generated `.tag` files.

Example:

```
$ cat Makefile
TARGETS_R := $(wildcard *.rst)
TARGETS_H := $(TARGETS_R:.rst=.html)

.PHONY: regular_files
regular_files: $(TARGETS_H)

%.html %.tag %.tagcheck: %.rst
        echo $< > $*.html; $(if $(findstring a,$<),touch $*.tag)
        touch $*.tagcheck

TAGS := $(wildcard *.tag)
NAVS := $(TAGS:.tag=.nav)

navigation.nav: $(NAVS)
        echo $^ > $@

%.nav: %.tag
        echo $< > $@

.PHONY: all
all: regular_files navigation.nav

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        -rm -f *.html *.tag *.tagcheck *.nav navigation.nav

ifneq ($(findstring clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),clean)
  -include $(TARGETS_R:.rst=.tagcheck)
endif
```

Suppose we have three `.rst` files and two of them generate `.tag` files (in our example rule it will generate `.tag` file when `.rst` file includes `a` in its name):

```
$ touch foo.rst bar.rst baz.rst
$ make all
echo foo.rst > foo.html;
touch foo.tagcheck
echo baz.rst > baz.html; touch baz.tag
touch baz.tagcheck
echo bar.rst > bar.html; touch bar.tag
touch bar.tagcheck
echo bar.tag > bar.nav
echo baz.tag > baz.nav
echo bar.nav baz.nav > navigation.nav
```

Note that everything is built in one pass. All the dependencies are correct and will rebuild those and only those files that are needed:

```
$ make all
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
$ touch foo.rst
$ make all
echo foo.rst > foo.html;
touch foo.tagcheck
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
$ touch bar.rst
$ make all
echo bar.rst > bar.html; touch bar.tag
touch bar.tagcheck
echo bar.tag > bar.nav
echo bar.nav baz.nav > navigation.nav
```